# How can I know programmatically if my spark program is running in local or cluster mode?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to know at runtime whether the program is being run in local mode (just one node) or a cluster (for example yarn-client or yarn-cluster)?

Comment: Print  the SparkConf properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `master` property:

```
spark.sparkContext.master: String
```

Comment: I see, would the value of this differ for spark local (just one node) or spark standalone cluster?

Answer (score 3):

You can directly call

```
spark.sparkContext.isLocal
```